# How to read in existing data into Quill JS

Tags: javascript, json, quill

I am having real trouble understanding how to work with quill...

Saving the data is not a problem as that pretty straight forward :)

I am a little stuck on two points

1. How to edit the saved data in quill
2. How to parse the saved data to create a static page

can anyone offer any advice how to load the delta

```
{"ops":[{"insert":"this is a test bit of text\n"}]}
```

back into the quill editor and how to parse the output to create a page?

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Answer (score 22):

Use [setContents](http://quilljs.com/docs/api/#setcontents) to insert a delta:

```
quill.setContents({
    "ops":[
        {"insert":"this is a test bit of text\n"}
    ]
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKWZLd

You can access the raw HTML with:

```
var html = document.querySelector(".ql-editor").innerHTML
```

If you are working with raw HTML, you need to sanitize it before you use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I have tried this before using the setContents API but it just outputs the string of text "{"ops":[{"insert":"this is a test bit of text\n"}]}" and doesnt create the form.

Comment: The codepen link above show you a live demo of setContents. By form you mean the text editor?

Answer (score 20):

This works for me. May it will helps some one.

```
editor.root.innerHTML = "<p><strong class=\"ql-size-large\"><em><s><u>This would be the text that we are going to show in the editor with pre-formatting.<\/u><\/s><\/em><\/strong><\/p>";
```

Here `editor` will be your quill instance.

Thanks to this [LINK](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZypOM)

Comment: Good answer.. Thanks

Comment: This is not a good answer for the question, and it's not good practice if you're accepting HTML from user input. Use the deltas to prevent attacks.

Answer (score 5):

I write this for people who is using Laravel. I did it like this:

To store, before submit my form:

```
        form.submit(function(){
            var description = document.querySelector('input[name=description]');
            description.value = editor.root.innerHTML;                
        })
```

To edit my form, I load the content:

```
         var editor = new Quill('#quill-editor', {
            modules: {
                toolbar: toolbarOptions
            },
            placeholder: 'type something',
            theme: 'snow'
        });
        .root.innerHTML = '{!! !empty($quill_editor) ? $quill_editor : ''  !!} ';
```

And if finally you want to use is as html, you can load it like this in your template:

```
{!! $description !!}
```

I hope is useful for someone

Comment: I can confirm the above solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

- Create the editor (the example below is for a read only version)
- Locate your target (where you want the text to be displayed)
- Parse your string content
- [setContents](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#setcontents) for your editor

---

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', { modules: { toolbar: [] }, readOnly: true, theme: 'bubble'} );
var $target = $('#editor-container');
var $content = JSON.parse($target[0].innerText);
quill.setContents($content);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// parse String
let stringToParse = String.raw`{"ops":[{"insert":"this is a test bit of text\n"}]}`;
// set quill editor instance to Delta state.
quill.setContents(JSON.parse());
```

[setContents](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#setcontents) from Quill to set editor to Delta.

[String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) to avoid expanding `'\t'` to `' '`. (see also [JSON.parse throws error when parsing...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238588/json-parse-throws-error-when-parsing-json-that-has-html-content/57010974))

Answer (score 2):

Quill parses content by its own method.

If you are using HTML directly, use **[dangerouslyPasteHTML](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/#dangerouslypastehtml)** like the following:

```
quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML("<p>here is some <strong>awesome</strong> text</p>");
```

This will sanitize the HTML by its own method and load HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I was setting `root.innerHTML`, but it messes up the actual HTML, the `pasteHTML` method seems to be working fine, like so:

```
quill.pasteHTML(YOUR_HTML_HERE, 'silent');
```

I also got a code editor, and using following method:

```
let delta = quill.editor.getDelta();
delta.insert(VALUE_HERE, { 'code-block': true });
quill.updateContents(delta, 'silent');
```

You may also need to clear your contents before using the `getDelta` method above, like so:

```
quill.setContents([
  { insert: '\n', attributes: { 'code-block': true } }
], 'silent');
```

I use to `silent` the [Source](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#events) so this change is not triggered on my own binded event listeners.

Answer (score -1):

So I have managed to find a work around, not sure if it is the correct method, but it works.

Turns out it was javascript escaping the data passed to it.

Essentially when the form fails to submit the errored data  is added back to the hidden input field and then javascript reads it from there...

HTML Form:

```
<input name="post" id="post" type="hidden" data-post-id="{{ old('post') }}">
```

Javascript:

```
var postId = $('#post').data("post-id");
quill.setContents(postId);
```